# Запись дерева Хаффмана в файл Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, huffman

При реализации алгоритма Хаффмана на Python возник вопрос о записи в файл дерева. Как я понимаю сперва нужно узнать размер дерева, затем записать это значение, а затем и само дерево. При декодировании мы считываем размер, и затем дерево. Только как это реализовать не совсем пониаю. Дерево предствляет собой список с элементами типа Node. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://proglib.io/p/kak-hranit-obekty-python-so-slozhnoy-strukturoy-moduli-pickle-i-dill-2020-04-30

Comment: Спасибо. После того, как я с помощью модуля pickle записал дерево в файл, как мне понять при чтении, когда начинаются сами закодированные данные?

Comment: ну если вы сериализовали в файл некоторый объект, то при десериализации у вас будет опять этот же объект со всеми данными.